# mongodb error: exception: Invalid JSON passed to mongoimport: code BadValue: BadValue: Year out of range: 1944

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I would like to import json to mongodb with command

```
mongoimport --host localhost --port 3001 --db meteor --type json --jsonArray --collection Client --file /home/mirka/client.json
```

and my JSON file looks like this (I paste only part of JSON because it is too long)

```
[...{"_id":"69","firstName":"examplefirstname","lastName":"examplelastname","pesel":{"pesel":<person's ID number INT32>},"zipCode":"00-000","city":"examplecity","street":"examplestreer","house":"1A","local":"3","signDate":{"date":{"$date":"2016-09-23T00:00:00Z"}},"email":"exampleemail@gmail.com","phone":123456789,"coInsured":{"pesel":{}},"salaried":{"firstName":"examplefirstname","lastName":"examplelastname","bornDate":{"date":{"$date":"1944-03-02T00:00:00Z"}}},"insuranceStartDate":{"date":{"$date":"2016-10-08T00:00:00Z"}},"insuranceEndDate":{"date":{"$date":"2017-10-07T00:00:00Z"}}},...]
```

and my problem is that I can import first records of JSON file and when it's time to import this part of JSON file I have an error

> exception: Invalid JSON passed to mongoimport: code BadValue: BadValue: Year out of range:  1944

How to solve it?

MongoDB 2.6.10

PS I migrate database from MySQL to MongoDB. That's why I import JSON to mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this jira [TOOLS-609](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-609), and ensure that you are using the right version of mongodb.

In the jira it is mentioned that the fix version is 2.8.0-rc2, and you are using an older version 2.6, go for a newer version and your problem will be solved.